# Parallel Multi-instance is getting created user tasks with last employee details

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I am developing a scenario on Camunda bpm Modeler 5 and bpm run 7.17.
**Scenario:**
using a service task to invoke an external rest-api using http-connector and that external rest api sends response as follows with multiple employees info in json format.

```
  [
    {"regId":"0XFY1FX00W","fname":"abc","lname":"def","email":"abc.def@gmail.com"},
    {"regId":"0XFY1F000X","fname":"ghi","lname":"jklm","email":"ghi.jklm@ymail.com"},
    {"regId":"0XFY1F000Y","fname":"nop","lname":"qrs","email":"nop.qrs@xmail.com"},
    {"regId":"0XFY1F000Z","fname":"tuv","lname":"wxyz","email":"tuv.wxyz@zmail.com"}
    ]
```

I am trying to create 4 user tasks with those 4 employees and those user tasks should be populated with those employee first name and last names.
I have used parallel multi-instance and I succeeded with that 4 user tasks creation but all the user tasks contain last employee details i.e.

`"fname":"tuv","lname":"wxyz"`.

Please let me know how to achieve that i.e. the user tasks should contain 4 different employee details?

*Note: I have tested with sequence multi-task and it is working as expected and My requirement is to use user task and not any subprocess.*

Comment: Please add the details of how you have configured the multi-instance task. What are you using as element variable and how are you referencing the element in the user task?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? could you please share ?